# Use iso image for virt-builder

Tags: linux, kvm

the virt command works fine with the distributions from the list(debian-11 for example), but can I somehow use my own iso-file as a source? At the output, I need to have a qcow2 file with an OS and preinstalled commands like this:

```
virt-builder debian-11 \
--size 8G \
--output /var/lib/libvirt/images/gitlab-runner-base.qcow2 \
--format qcow2 \
--hostname gitlab-runner-bullseye \
--network \
--install curl \
--run-command 'curl -L "https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh" | bash' \
--run-command 'curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh" | bash' \
--run-command 'useradd -m -p "" gitlab-runner -s /bin/bash' \
--install gitlab-runner,git,git-lfs,openssh-server \
--run-command "git lfs install --skip-repo" \
--ssh-inject gitlab-runner:file:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub \
--run-command "echo 'gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers" \
--run-command "sed -E 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"\"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0\"/' -i /etc/default/grub" \
--run-command "grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg" \
--run-command "echo 'auto eth0' >> /etc/network/interfaces" \
--run-command "echo 'allow-hotplug eth0' >> /etc/network/interfaces" \
--run-command "echo 'iface eth0 inet dhcp' >> /etc/network/interfaces"
```